# Цвет input range

Tags: html, css

как сделать из такого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
такой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]плюс чтобы цвет и размеры не менялись

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #1B2FB2;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    margin: 12px 0px 5px 0px;
    width: 190px;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #1B2FB2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type = "range" min = "0" max = "100" value = "50" class = "slider">
```

Comment: Тогда показывайте код "такого"... вам же правку помочь сделать - нужен код, добавьте его, пожалуста, в текст вопроса.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Обновил свой вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');

slider.oninput = function(){
  progress.style.width = `${this.value}%`;
};
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 190px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
/*     background: #1B2FB2; */
    background-color: #ccc;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    margin: 12px 0px 5px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #1B2FB2;
}
.progress{
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #1B2FB2;
  top: calc(50% + 1.5px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type = "range" min = "0" max = "100" value = "50" class = "slider">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```